# Java ArrayList size() method return 0 instead of actual length of the ArrayList

Tags: java, class, inheritance, arraylist, size

I am learning Java and followed a tutorial like this:

```
package segovia.java.learn;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GroceryList {
    private ArrayList<String> groceryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addGroceryItem(String item) {
        groceryList.add(item);
    }

    public void printGroceryList() {
        System.out.println("You have " + groceryList.size() + " items in your grocery list.");
        for (int i=0; i < groceryList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + groceryList.get(i));
        }
    }

    public int getLength(){
        return groceryList.size();
    }
}
```

```
package segovia.java.learn;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroceryList myGroceries = new GroceryList();
        myGroceries.addGroceryItem("apple");
        myGroceries.addGroceryItem("orange");
        myGroceries.addGroceryItem("pork");
        myGroceries.addGroceryItem("beef");
        myGroceries.printGroceryList();

        System.out.println(myGroceries.getLength());
    }
}
```

which worked fine. However, I thought that since the `myGroceries` is an ArrayList, so it should have the `.size()` method. So I added a line of

```
System.out.println(myGroceries.size());
```

but IntelliJ told me it's not working. So I thought that MAYBE I should use inheritance so I changed to

```
public class GroceryList extends ArrayList {
```

now the `.size()` method is working, but it gave me a wrong value.

**Final codes are like this:**

```
package segovia.java.learn;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GroceryList extends ArrayList{
    private ArrayList<String> groceryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addGroceryItem(String item) {
        groceryList.add(item);
    }

    public void printGroceryList() {
        System.out.println("You have " + groceryList.size() + " items in your grocery list.");
        for (int i=0; i < groceryList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + groceryList.get(i));
        }
    }

    public int getLength(){
        return groceryList.size();
    }
}
```

```
package segovia.java.learn;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroceryList myGroceries = new GroceryList();
        myGroceries.addGroceryItem("apple");
        myGroceries.addGroceryItem("orange");
        myGroceries.addGroceryItem("pork");
        myGroceries.addGroceryItem("beef");
        myGroceries.printGroceryList();

        System.out.println(myGroceries.getLength());
        System.out.println(myGroceries.size());
    }
}
```

and the `getLenth()` gave me 4, which is correct, while the `.size()` gave me 0, which is obviously wrong.
[image]

Can anyone help me understand why the codes work like this? I guess it's related to the class inheritance but not sure.

Comment: `myGroceries is an ArrayList`, no it's not.  You don't declare `GroceryList extends ArrayList` so why would it be an ArrayList?  It *has a* private ArrayList, that's all.

Comment: The first version of `GroceryList` is not an `ArrayList` - it merely **contains** an `ArrayList` and has only the methods that your class defines. The second version of `GroveryList` then is an `ArrayList` **and** contains an `ArrayList`. Even in the second version you only add items to the contained `ArrayList`, but nothing to the "ArrayList" that your `GroceryList` extends (i.e. you always call `GroceryList.addGroceryItem()` but never the `GroceryList.add()` method add would actually change the size).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding of inheritance vs composition. In this case, before you added `extends ArrayList` to `GroceryList`, your `GroceryList` **has a list**. That's why `.size()` wasn't working on it, because the `GroceryList` you defined doesn't have a `size` method. It does have a list called `groceryList` though. That's why after you `addGroceryItem`, the `getLength` method works correctly. It's getting the size of `groceryList`.

After you added `extends ArrayList`, `GroceryList` now **is** an `ArrayList`, that's why it has a `size` method now. But it is not the same list as `groceryList`. Hence getting the size of `myGroceries`, after `addGroceryItem` doesn't give you the size you expected. Because you never added anything to the `ArrayList` that is `myGroceries`. You've only added thing to the `groceryList` that is a field in `myGroceries`.